# Symfony 4.2: How to get Encoder Instance outside of Controller

Tags: symfony

I need to check my password in Login form, so
I want to get the Encoder in class Authenticator (made by bin/console make:auth) in function `checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)`.

The $credentials['password'] is plain text, and the $user->getPassword() is encoded password.

My security.yaml is:

```
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost: 12
```

How to get instance of the Encoder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the encoder from the encoder factory which has a `security.encoder_factory` service ID (or `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface` interface if using autowiring).

After injecting the factory, you can get the encoder for a specific user entity with:

```
use App\Entity\User;

...

$encoder = $encoderFactory->getEncoder(User:class);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, and how can I inject the encoderFactory?

Comment: It's already in the answer :) If you're using autowiring, just typehint `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface` interface. If not, use `security.encoder_factory` service.

Comment: Ok, I've got it already. Just read the file LoginFormAuthenticator.tpl.php and made changes according to user_needs_encoder.

Comment: I've just added the UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder as constructor parameter. I'm surprised it works, but happy :)

Comment: Or not... The $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $credentials['password']); makes for me different hash than I've expected.